# Does client-side java work on a server?

Tags: java, android, jsp, intellij-idea

Can I write client side java in intelliJ, and then simply put it on a server for it to run on a server? Or will I need to write in a specialised version of Java and need to use a specialised IDE instead?

I'm trying to make an app and run the primary functions on a server then have the app send requests and fetch the data from the server. (It will esentially be a search engine of sorts and queries will be made to the server, which will then apply filters and use my algorithms to perform a search, before returning a result to the mobile device). But I'm not sure if I can begin writing this java on intellij, just as I would when making say, a simple calculator, or if I would need to write the java using a specialised server variation and server IDE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java language is the same no matter what, so your logic can be ported easily.  However on a server you may use a framework that's different from one you'd use on a client (for example you tagged this android-  there wouldn't be Activities or Views on a server.  You'd use another framework instead, possibly Spring.)  Or you could go frameworkless, but then you'll have to write a lot of code that the frameworks do for you.

As for IDE-  an IDE is an editor.  You can write Java in notepad if you want.  There's no difference, its just what features make your life easier.  And yes, IntelliJ is a common choice.

Comment: Thank you very much! I read about a framework called PlayFramework? Would you recommend this or Spring for android development?

Comment: For Android development you use the Android Framework.  You don't really have a choice, on Android its the only way to get things to run.  Spring is typically a server side framework.

Comment: Sorry I meant server side, to integrate it with the android application, unless I would just send data in JSON format for example? Then I would just be able to use any server side framework, such as Spring?

Comment: You can use any server side technology you want.  That's part of the point of a webservice-  your interface is a specific JSON/XML/other schema, and you can implement that with any language and any set of technologies.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! It's very much appreciated! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like make your own website, you should go with JavaEE or better with Spring.

If you would like to make simple server side application which will listen on specific port then respond something, go with [Sockets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm)

[Netty](http://netty.io/) is interesting NIO Socket library

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at Spring as both you and Gabe have mentioned, very much appreciate the help!